# Android - ListView Item Change Height of Item

Tags: android, android-layout, accordion

I have a Custom ListView that has some TextView & a Button, The default height of ListView Item View is 100dp but on button click I want to increase the height of that specific Row Item to the e.g. 500dp. The problem is I can increase the height of row but it doesn't increase the height of List Content View[image]

This is when list is collapsed once I click "+" button it expands but it looks really odd.
[image]

What I need to make it look like is Accordion Type View.

**Code to Change the Height:**

```
LinearLayout row_view = (LinearLayout)v.getParent().getParent().getParent().getParent().getParent().getParent();
                if(mCurrentBg == R.drawable.widget_minus)
                {
                    v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.widget_plus);
                    mCurrentBg = R.drawable.widget_plus;
                    row_view.getLayoutParams().height = (int) Common.convertDpToPixel(100, context);                    
                }
                else
                {
                    mCurrentBg = R.drawable.widget_minus;
                    row_view.getLayoutParams().height =(int) Common.convertDpToPixel(700, context);                 
                    v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.widget_minus);                   
                }
                row_view.requestLayout();
                row_view.invalidate();
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked out Android's [ExpandableListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html)?

Answer (score 1):

please check this open source library which implement the Accordion Layout here : [Android Accordion View](https://github.com/hamsterready/android-accordion-view#android-accordion-view) .

and please give me feedback

Hope That Helps .